# Why do I get 'Expected ... to define ScheduledJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class like this

```
class RecurringJob
  include ScheduledJob

  run_every 1.hours

  def perform
    puts "perform job"
  end
end
```

I get an error saying:

> Expected D:/ASM/source/app/lib/jobs/scheduled_job.rb to define ScheduledJob

The file definition is this:

```
module Delayed
 module ScheduledJob

def self.included(base)
  base.extend(ClassMethods)
  base.class_eval do
    @@logger = Delayed::Worker.logger
    cattr_reader :logger
  end
end
    ....

 end
end
```

What does the error mean? Isn't that a definition?

### EDIT

I you must know, the class was defined inside a rake task (which is empty except for the class, and I have no idea if that is permitted).

More verbose error:

```
Expected D:/ASM/source/app/lib/jobs/scheduled_job.rb to define ScheduledJob
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
D:/Software/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
D:/ASM/source/app/lib/tasks/sandbox.rake:29:in `<class:RecurringJob>'
D:/ASM/source/app/lib/tasks/sandbox.rake:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What's the name of the file that contains these definitions? The 'Expected X to define Y' error usually means that the file that defines a class doesn't have the name Rails expects.

Comment: Filename : scheduled_job.rb

Comment: Added : require 'jobs/scheduled_job' on top of my task file and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails follows a very strict naming conventions and that includes lib files.

If you want to define A ScheduledJob module inside the Delayed module your file will have to be named `/lib/delayed/scheduled_job.rb`

This will make Rails expectations and your naming to match.